# Passing a Go map that is in a structure

Tags: dictionary, go

This code (at Go Playground at http://play.golang.org/p/BjWPVdQQrS):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type foodStruct struct {
    fruit map[int]string
    veggie map[int]string
}

func showFood(f map[int]map[int]string) {
    fmt.Println(f[1][1])
}

func main() {
    f := map[int]foodStruct{
        1: {
            fruit: map[int]string{1: "pear"},
            veggie: map[int]string{1: "celery"},
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(f[1].fruit[1])

    g := map[int]map[int]string{1: map[int]string{1: "orange"}}
    showFood(g)

    // showFood(f.fruit) // Compile error: "f.fruit undefined (type map[int]foodStruct has no field or method fruit)"
}
```

prints:

```
pear
orange
```

Is there any way I can pass a form of variable *f* to showFood(), so that it prints "pear"? Passing f.fruit raises the compile error shown in the commented-out line above. The error is confusing to me, since foodStruct does have field fruit.

Comment: Well, `f` is not a `foodStruct`, it is a `map[int]foodStruct`. So of course it doesn't have a `fruit` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems.

First, `foodStruct` does have a field `fruit`, but `f` is not a `foodStruct`. It's a `map[int]foodStruct`, which doesn't have any fields or methods at all.

Second, nowhere in `f` is there anything that has the type `map[int]map[int]string`. There's no way to pass any part of `f` into `showFood` without creating a new map of the correct type.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks to you and nneonneo.